# dynamic table where i can click on link and grab contextual information

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, html

i am generated a table dynamically which looks like this:

Name     Action
====     =======
Adam     Delete
Joe      Delete
Bill     Delete

I want "Delete" to be a link that pops up a confirmation popup that says:

"Are you sure you want to delete "Adam"?  (Yes, No)

NOTE that "adam" is contextual and needs to be retrieved from the row of the table where the user selected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
        //prevent the link from going anywhere
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //give me this link's parent (a <td>) and grab the text of the 'prev' one
        var name = $(this).parent().prev('td').text();
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + name);
    });
});
```

Assuming you give your delete links the class `delete`.

Comment: In your $(document).ready(), within script tags, in the HEAD of your document.

Comment: sorry for being a pain, but i am still lost.  i put this on top, but where do a associate the link with this function ?

Comment: is ".delete" the id i have to give some div around my link?

Comment: .delete is the class you would give your delete links, e.g. <a class="delete" ...>

Comment: @me - let me know if you need any more help, it's not a bother.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on every table structure that you mentioned.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- you will need jQuery -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/jquery.js' ></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    $("td[innerHTML*='delete']").click(function(e) {

        var name = $(this).prev('td').text();

        if( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + name) )
        {
          // call ajax to delete this record

          // remove tr element
          $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- your table -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Mira</td>
        <td>delete</td>
      </tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>delete</td>
      <tr>
        <td>Barney</td>
        <td>delete</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Scott</td>
        <td>delete</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```